# why http.post didn't call my controller in angular 2

Tags: typescript, angular

this is my service in my angular2 project and I would like to use the create method in the service to call my controller.

```
 create(maillingId: string, name: string, phone: string): Observable<void> {      
    var rp = new RecipientDto(maillingId, name, phone);

    console.log(JSON.stringify(rp));
    console.log(this.apiUrl);
    console.log(this.headers); 

    return this.http.post(this.apiUrl, JSON.stringify(rp), { headers: this.headers })
        .do(null,
        () => {
        })
        .map<any>(response => { });

}
```

this is what I print out[image: in my chrome console]
this is my workable postman call[image: workable postman call]
and last is my controller code

```
 [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Post([FromBody]RecipientDto recipientDto)
    {
        MailingList ml = _repository.Get<MailingList>(recipientDto.MaillingId);

        if (ml != null)
        {               
            var rp = new Recipient(Guid.NewGuid());             
            rp.IsActivated = true;
            rp.Name = recipientDto.Name;
            rp.PhoneNumber = recipientDto.Phone;
            ml.Recipients.Add(rp);        
            return Ok();
        }
        return HttpNotFound();          
    }
```

one thing to mention that there is no fiddler record when my front-end create method is called.

same question for delete(also don't call the api) but for the getAll() is workable

```
 getAll(id:string): Observable<Recipient[]> {       

    return this.http.get(`${this.apiUrl+'/'+id}`)
        .map<any>(res => <any>res.json())
        .map(a=> <Recipient[]>a);;

}
```

and my controller for get

```
 [HttpGet("{mlId}")]
    public IEnumerable<Recipient> Get(string mlId)
    {         
        List<Recipient> list = _repository.Get<MailingList>(mlId).Recipients;

        return list;
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried removing the `.do(null, () => {})` from your `post` call? I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish with that.

Comment: tried but still didn't work. fiddler didn't appear any record.

Comment: Do you `subscribe` to your `create` method? I believe that Observables won't actually fire until they are subscribed to.

Comment: Hi It turns out you have to subscribe the post call otherwise it won't call the api

Answer (score 6):

I have a working post sample here:

```
var headers = new Headers();
headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
this.http.post('http://some-url/', 
                       JSON.stringify({firstName:'Joe',lastName:'Smith'}),
                       {headers:headers})
.map((res: Response) => res.json())
.subscribe((res:Person) => this.postResponse = res);
```

Looks like you are missing the subscribe part.

Some more info here: 
http://www.syntaxsuccess.com/viewarticle/angular-2.0-and-http

Comment: thank you for the comment it works now.I didn't have the map() and subscribe() in my previous version