# Angular 2- calling http with observable not working. tried all option but not worked

Tags: angular, http, dictionary, observable

Not able to call web api using http in angular2. 
tried different solutions but still not help. So may opening new issue will help me.

tried below solutions but not helped:

[http with Observable in Angular 2 cant use data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41961693/http-with-observable-in-angular-2-cant-use-data)

[Angular2 - http.get not calling the webpi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43210472/angular2-http-get-not-calling-the-webpi)

[why http.post didn't call my controller in angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35143907/why-http-post-didnt-call-my-controller-in-angular-2)

Below is the source - please let me know if i am doing anything wrong:

"package.json"

```js
{
  "name": "Angular2Spa",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-server": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "3.0.0",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.38",
    "angular2-localstorage": "^0.4.0",
    "angular2-platform-node": "~2.0.10",
    "angular2-universal": "~2.0.10",
    "angular2-universal-polyfills": "~2.0.10",
    "aspnet-prerendering": "^1.0.6",
    "aspnet-webpack": "^1.0.11",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "css": "^2.2.1",
    "css-loader": "^0.25.0",
    "es6-shim": "^0.35.1",
    "expose-loader": "^0.7.1",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^1.0.1",
    "file-loader": "^0.9.0",
    "isomorphic-fetch": "^2.2.1",
    "jquery": "^2.2.1",
    "preboot": "^4.5.2",
    "raw-loader": "^0.5.1",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.0",
    "to-string-loader": "^1.1.5",
    "ts-loader": "^0.8.2",
    "typescript": "^2.0.0",
    "url-loader": "^0.5.7",
    "webpack": "^1.12.14",
    "webpack-externals-plugin": "^1.0.0",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "^2.10.0",
    "webpack-merge": "^0.14.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.21"
  }
}
```

"app.component.ts"

```js
import { Component, Inject } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'app',
    template: require('./app.component.html'),
    styles: [require('./app.component.css')]
})
export class AppComponent {
}


"app.module.ts"

import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { UniversalModule } from 'angular2-universal';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
//declare var localStorage: any;
// used to create fake backend
import { fakeBackendProvider } from './components/_helpers/index';
import { MockBackend, MockConnection } from '@angular/http/testing';
import { BaseRequestOptions, Http, HttpModule, Response } from '@angular/http';

import { AppComponent } from './components/app/app.component'
import { NavMenuComponent } from './components/navmenu/navmenu.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './components/home/home.component';
import { FetchDataComponent } from './components/fetchdata/fetchdata.component';
import { CounterComponent } from './components/counter/counter.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './components/login/index';
import { RegisterComponent } from './components/register/index';
import { AlertComponent } from './components/_directives/index';
import { AuthGuard } from './components/_guards/index';
import { AlertService, AuthenticationService, UserService, FetchDataService } from './components/_services/index';


@NgModule({
    bootstrap: [ AppComponent ],
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        NavMenuComponent,
        LoginComponent,
        RegisterComponent,
        CounterComponent,
        FetchDataComponent,
        HomeComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        FormsModule,
        UniversalModule, // Must be first import. This automatically imports BrowserModule, HttpModule, and JsonpModule too.
        //HttpModule,
        RouterModule.forRoot([
            { path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' },
            { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
            { path: 'counter', component: CounterComponent },
            { path: 'fetch-data', component: FetchDataComponent },
            { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
            { path: 'register', component: RegisterComponent },
            { path: '**', redirectTo: 'home' }
        ])
    ],
    providers: [
        AuthGuard,
        AlertService,
        AuthenticationService,
        UserService,
        FetchDataService,
        // providers used to create fake backend
        fakeBackendProvider,
        MockBackend,
        BaseRequestOptions
    ],
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

"fetchdata.component.ts"  (in this calling service)

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response, HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from "rxjs/Observable";
// Import RxJs required methods
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { AlertService, FetchDataService } from "../_services/index";

@Component({
    selector: 'fetchdata',
    template: require('./fetchdata.component.html')
})


export class FetchDataComponent implements OnInit{
    public forecasts: WeatherForecast[];
    array = Array<any>();
    loading: boolean;

    private baseUrl: string = 'http://localhost:2828/';

    //private fetchDataService: FetchDataService;
    constructor(
        private router: Router,
        private fetchDataService: FetchDataService,
        private alertService: AlertService,
        private http: Http) {
        //TRY-1   
        //this.http.get(this.baseUrl + 'api/SampleData/WeatherForecasts')
        //    .catch((error: any) => Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error'))
        //    .subscribe(result =>
        //    {
        //        this.forecasts = result.json();
        //    });


        //TRY-2
        //this.fetchDataService.getAll()
        //    .subscribe(
        //    data => {
        //        this.alertService.success('service called successfuly', true);
        //    },
        //    error => {
        //        this.alertService.error(error);
        //        this.loading = false;
        //    });

        //http.get('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos/1')
        //    .map((res: Response) => res.json())
        //    .subscribe(res => {
        //        this.array = res;
        //        this.loading = false;
        //    });

        //TRY-3
        //http.get('/api/SampleData/WeatherForecasts')
        //    .catch((error: any) => Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error'))
        //    .subscribe(result =>
        //    {
        //        this.forecasts = result.json();
        //    });
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.getMyData()
            .subscribe((res: any) => {
                console.log(res);
            },
            error => {
                // TODO: Error handling
                console.log(error);
            });
    }

    private getHeaders() {
        // I included these headers because otherwise FireFox
        // will request text/html instead of application/json
        let headers = new Headers();
        headers.append('Accept', 'application/json');
        return headers;
    }

    getMyData(): Observable<any> {
        var headers = new Headers();
        headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        return this.http.get('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos/1', headers)
            //.do(response => console.log("Result: " + JSON.stringify(response)))
            .map((res: Response) => {
                console.log(res);
                return res;
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                // TODO: Error handling
                console.log(err);
                return err;
            })
    };
}
```

Please let me know if anything wrong.

Comment: You should separate your http code into its own service. Also I would recommend cleaning up this post. Its kind of hard to read. Just include the relevant information. Probably don't need all the package.json info and or past failed attempts. Just the current attempt you are struggling with. Also see if you can reproduce the issue in http://plnkr.co/ that will help others understand what the issue is.

Comment: what error your getting for each try

Comment: WHAT IS THE ERROR?

Comment: There is no error but the get dosen't seem to go through even in browser's network i cannot find that get url being called.

Comment: Remove all fake backend things from your module. They will interfere with your real http-request. Also, like Kris said. Make a separate service for your http-requests. I also see some other problems with your code, e.g no need for headers here and trying to assign `res` to your variable. Should be `res.json()` But yeah, make a service, do requests there, subscribe in component. I suggest you take a look at the [official TOH tutorial for HTTP](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt6.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will be helpful to let know what error are you getting.
If you want to use headers, try changing

```
this.http.get('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos/1', headers)`
```

to

```
this.http.get('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos/1', { headers: headers })
```

Comment: Thanks for replay @Ashish. adding {headers: headers} showing me error : Build:Argument of type '{ headers: Headers; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'RequestOptionsArgs'. tried without header as well..but still not work.

Comment: Value for key headers shall be headers (variable headers, not Type Headers).